# TweetSharp Losing Connection When Restarting Debug Mode?

Tags: vb.net, tweetsharp

I'm storing the access token in the DB that I get via:

```
    Dim requestToken As New OAuthRequestToken With {.Token = oauthToken}
    Dim twitSvc As New TwitterService(SocialMediaService.TwitterConsumerKey, SocialMediaService.TwitterConsumerSecret)
    Dim accessToken As OAuthAccessToken = twitSvc.GetAccessToken(requestToken, oauthVerifier)

    twitSvc.AuthenticateWith(accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret)
```

Then, when I get the token and make a request in the same debug session, tweets are returned as expected. However, if I restart the debug mode and try and get the token/secret from the DB and make the same request again, the service returns `Nothing`.

```
    Dim token = db.AmpConfigs.Where(Function(c) c.name = "twitter_token" AndAlso c.type = "social").FirstOrDefault()
    Dim tokenSecret = db.AmpConfigs.Where(Function(c) c.name = "twitter_token_secret" AndAlso c.type = "social").FirstOrDefault()

    Dim twitSvc As New TwitterService(SocialMediaService.TwitterConsumerKey, SocialMediaService.TwitterConsumerSecret)

    twitSvc.AuthenticateWith(token.value, tokenSecret.value)

    Dim twitUser As TwitterUser = twitSvc.VerifyCredentials(New VerifyCredentialsOptions With {.IncludeEntities = True, .SkipStatus = False})

    Dim tweets = twitSvc.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(New ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions With {.Count = 100})
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with TweetSharp, but normally OAuth tokens have an expiration attached to them.  Is there any chance that the times when you have restarted your debugger that the tokens granted initially have been expired/invalidated?

Comment: No, I've tested that by simply restarting debug mode immediately after authenticating. It's very strange.